# Command line arguments: How to launch 7zFM.exe like the context menu does, so that prepared 7z GUI appears?

Tags: windows, 7-zip, context-menu, command-line-arguments

7z file manager (7zFM.exe) can be launched via context menu.

[image: 7z file manager Windows context menu entry]

This conveniently produces the 7z GUI already prepared for archiving. All I need to do is change the archive name and maybe add a password.

[image: 7z file manager GUI prepared for archiving]

This is possible. But just **how** can it be achieved via command line?

My searches on the Web and in the Registry were fruitless. I even wonder how there can be a 7z context menu entry if there appears to be no such thing in the Registry.

My goal is to significantly ease my multiple daily backup tasks, where I create archives with an incrementing archive name counter (e.g. "0004") for multiple projects (DTP and such). I would do this via batch files and/or a little Java program I'd make to derive the appropriate archive name (See counter.) to be prepared in the GUI, if such a detail can be defined via command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything was easy like this. - The Task Manager's "Details" tab gives it away. The syntax is:

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" a -ad -saa -- "D:\eula.2052.txt"`

I left out the `-i#7zMap7448:36:7zEvent28001` part because apparently that refers to the immediate user action that could somehow be evaluated by the program, but the command line start doesn't have such action, so the error in the screenshot appears.

Also in the screenshot: The result of the *proper* call, the one without that extra argument.

Due to dumb luck, I also immediately figured out how to do all that *with giving a desired file name*:

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" a -ad -saa "BLABLABLA" -- "D:\eula.2052.txt"`

This opens the shown window with the desired file name plus ".7z", and confirming the dialog will indeed compress the desired file into an archive of the file name, which is *different* from the file.

[image]

**BY THE WAY - STORING CREATION DATE ETC:**

If you manually add "tc ta tm" (created, accessed, modified), all those three dates will be part of the archive, will be restored upon unpacking, and the GUI will remember these parameters for next time.

**This is probably overlooked my most. Hence ... THE BOLD!**

(I find it ridiculous that this behavior isn't the default, after all you want to transfer a copy of your current file/folder reality 1:1 into the future, so the dates should be part of it.)

[image]